# Identify Facebook object type from user notification

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm reading the user/notifications facebook stream (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/notification/).
As part of the result i'm getting an Object.
"The object (this can be a post, a photo, a comment, etc.) that was the subject of the notification."

Is there a way to identify if the object is post or comment or like etc'?

Thanks,
    fredy

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the type of a Facebook Object if you using something Facebook call "Introspection" by adding metadata argument to your request:

```
GET http://graph.facebook.com/object_id?metadata=1
```

The resulting JSON will include a metadata property that lists all the supported edges for the given node and a **type field**

Find more on : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4 under the section *Introspection*.